# Is there an #ifdef in Qt to determine if we're building for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, conditional-compilation

I have an Android-specific fix in my Qt application, and I want that code to be compiled only when building for Android.

Is there an `#if` or `#ifdef` that will do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can find it [in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_ANDROID), so just use:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
```